# Highlight two class of checkbox with different colour

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a table containing two columns of checkboxes used for two different purpose. I want to highlight them when clicked with two different colours. How to edit my code to get the desired result

```
<style>
    a1.highlight {
        background-color:grey;
    }

    a2.highlight {
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>

echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='cb1[$no]' id='cb1{$no}' class='a1'></td>";
echo "<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='cb2[$no]' id='cb2{$no}' class='a2'></td>";
```

Comment: Please add any Javascript you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have the CSS in-place for the colours and the only thing missing is the event to change the colour.

To do this you could use some pretty simple jQuery like so:

```
$('.a1,.a2').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

The above will attach the `highlighted` class once either `a1` or `a2` has been clicked on.

Comment: won't work as there is no such elements in html `a1, a2`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i've edited this to target the classes of `a1` and `a2`